# Test case failed with org.junit.ComparisonFailure

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd, testcase

While having the unit test case writing for French and Czech localization, on doing

```
  assertThat(formattedDecimal).isEqualTo("8 771,23");
```

where `formattedDecimal` is a string ,
had a result

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"8 771,23"
Actual   :"8 771,23"
```

why it failed? did not understand, please guide what i am doing wrong here!!

Comment: Is `formattedDecimal` a `String`, or some other type?  It would need to be a `String` for this assertion to pass, since you're comparing it to a `String`.

Comment: formattedDecimal  is a string

Comment: OK, use a debugger to inspect the value of `formattedDecimal` to make sure there aren't any unexpected characters in there, for example, a non-breaking space instead of an ordinary space.

Comment: sure, will check on the same, however space is there as seen.

Comment: After debugging did not seen the difference by visuals but interestingly when copied Actual to do isEqualTo, it worked. Really confused

Comment: Maybe you're inadvertently running an earlier version of your code.  Try cleaning out your build directory and recompiling.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Beyond that: I would simply write code that compares both strings character by character to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your `formattedDecimal` including some control letters that can't see in the console. have you tried this?

```
assertThat("foo\bo").isNotEqualTo("foo");// ok
          //   ^--- it print "foo"             

assertThat(formattedDecimal.getBytes()).isEqualTo("8 771,23".getBytes())
```